# Empty Polygon when reading GeoJSON with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geojson, geometry, geopandas

I am reading a GeoJSON file to a GeoPandas dataframe. The GeoJSON has a bunch of polygon with admin boundaries for a city. When I read it to my GeoPandas df, the geometry column shows as empty polygons. What am I doing/interpreting wrong?

My resulting GeoPandas dataframe:

[image]

And my code to read it:

```
quartiers = gpd.read_file(quartiers_fpath)
```

This is a sample of the data I am trying to load:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "health_boundaries_sample",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "relation/12885662",
                "@id": "relation/12885662",
                "attribution": "Référentiel Géographique Commun (RGC.cd)",
                "boundary": "health",
                "health_level": "8",
                "name": "Baobao",
                "ref:dhis2": null,
                "type": "boundary",
                "is_in:health_level6": null,
                "source": "Ecole de sante Suisse",
                "source:date": "2018",
                "Nom": null,
                "waterway": null,
                "@relations": null,
                "fixme": null,
                "highway": null
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            1705820.503212230512872,
                            -487621.072047681955155
                        ],
                        [
                            1705848.600251707015559,
                            -487542.161416564078536
                        ],
                        [
                            1705856.370352164143696,
                            -487516.237481848627795
                        ],
                        [
                            1705875.929186696419492,
                            -487458.885549758619163
                        ],
                        [
                            1705892.393339384580031,
                            -487396.219370316655841
                        ],
                        [
                            1705912.6980145056732,
                            -487332.02370694844285
                        ],
                        [
                            1705926.43483966961503,
                            -487282.754964290885255
                        ],
                        [
                            1705950.624565018806607,
                            -487186.617920490622055
                        ],
                        [
                            1705980.380264907842502,
                            -487049.630359925795346
                        ],
                        [
                            1705880.292910735588521,
                            -487011.98394002096029
                        ],
                        [
                            1705421.311518245842308,
                            -486875.811666356865317
                        ],
                        [
                            1705345.436153321294114,
                            -487102.527404410298914
                        ],
                        [
                            1705294.15126391290687,
                            -487271.981268483097665
                        ],
                        [
                            1705239.704900965793058,
                            -487446.07989694387652
                        ],
                        [
                            1705295.064083737321198,
                            -487463.049899352830835
                        ],
                        [
                            1705397.433487470960245,
                            -487492.055214076128323
                        ],
                        [
                            1705487.81378204585053,
                            -487516.24864633224206
                        ],
                        [
                            1705590.53940814989619,
                            -487545.957342218840495
                        ],
                        [
                            1705650.340238604228944,
                            -487562.89387143048225
                        ],
                        [
                            1705693.253902304684743,
                            -487575.956325440492947
                        ],
                        [
                            1705746.097264584386721,
                            -487591.48613453033613
                        ],
                        [
                            1705820.503212230512872,
                            -487621.072047681955155
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "relation/12886371",
                "@id": "relation/12886371",
                "attribution": "Référentiel Géographique Commun (RGC.cd)",
                "boundary": "health",
                "health_level": "8",
                "name": "Uele",
                "ref:dhis2": null,
                "type": "boundary",
                "is_in:health_level6": "Makala",
                "source": "Ecole de sante Suisse",
                "source:date": "2018",
                "Nom": null,
                "waterway": null,
                "@relations": null,
                "fixme": null,
                "highway": null
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            1704845.990125927841291,
                            -486692.324985607643612
                        ],
                        [
                            1704829.837667813990265,
                            -486744.429133295547217
                        ],
                        [
                            1704814.286334950244054,
                            -486796.488655853609089
                        ],
                        [
                            1704800.827808513306081,
                            -486845.879920559877064
                        ],
                        [
                            1704787.090983349597082,
                            -486895.148405996966176
                        ],
                        [
                            1704772.296623022761196,
                            -486946.806103603681549
                        ],
                        [
                            1704759.327902345918119,
                            -486987.857640082715079
                        ],
                        [
                            1704743.420347111299634,
                            -487040.028958222654182
                        ],
                        [
                            1704731.253126767463982,
                            -487090.41400060034357
                        ],
                        [
                            1704719.097038372652605,
                            -487141.692227991647087
                        ],
                        [
                            1704706.3286927791778,
                            -487198.061471763940062
                        ],
                        [
                            1704693.649402777664363,
                            -487248.36845817201538
                        ],
                        [
                            1704681.994252091273665,
                            -487297.190602403716184
                        ],
                        [
                            1704873.563963797641918,
                            -487350.679519867291674
                        ],
                        [
                            1705239.704900965793058,
                            -487446.07989694387652
                        ],
                        [
                            1705294.15126391290687,
                            -487271.981268483097665
                        ],
                        [
                            1705345.436153321294114,
                            -487102.527404410298914
                        ],
                        [
                            1705421.311518245842308,
                            -486875.811666356865317
                        ],
                        [
                            1704845.990125927841291,
                            -486692.324985607643612
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "relation/12886381",
                "@id": "relation/12886381",
                "attribution": "Référentiel Géographique Commun (RGC.cd)",
                "boundary": "health",
                "health_level": "8",
                "name": "Selo",
                "ref:dhis2": null,
                "type": "boundary",
                "is_in:health_level6": "Makala",
                "source": "Ecole de sante Suisse",
                "source:date": "2018",
                "Nom": null,
                "waterway": null,
                "@relations": null,
                "fixme": null,
                "highway": null
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            1704255.918901080265641,
                            -487235.975922094017733
                        ],
                        [
                            1704345.341848034411669,
                            -487257.244194599275943
                        ],
                        [
                            1704412.30052174674347,
                            -487275.386426075536292
                        ],
                        [
                            1704542.856020549079403,
                            -487313.312075908994302
                        ],
                        [
                            1704667.06630837591365,
                            -487348.245667317416519
                        ],
                        [
                            1704681.994252091273665,
                            -487297.190602403716184
                        ],
                        [
                            1704693.649402777664363,
                            -487248.36845817201538
                        ],
                        [
                            1704706.3286927791778,
                            -487198.061471763940062
                        ],
                        [
                            1704719.097038372652605,
                            -487141.692227991647087
                        ],
                        [
                            1704731.253126767463982,
                            -487090.41400060034357
                        ],
                        [
                            1704743.420347111299634,
                            -487040.028958222654182
                        ],
                        [
                            1704759.327902345918119,
                            -486987.857640082715079
                        ],
                        [
                            1704772.296623022761196,
                            -486946.806103603681549
                        ],
                        [
                            1704787.090983349597082,
                            -486895.148405996966176
                        ],
                        [
                            1704800.827808513306081,
                            -486845.879920559877064
                        ],
                        [
                            1704814.286334950244054,
                            -486796.488655853609089
                        ],
                        [
                            1704829.837667813990265,
                            -486744.429133295547217
                        ],
                        [
                            1704845.990125927841291,
                            -486692.324985607643612
                        ],
                        [
                            1704571.131171210668981,
                            -486599.616078744002152
                        ],
                        [
                            1704534.150836369022727,
                            -486593.989240879076533
                        ],
                        [
                            1704517.964982407633215,
                            -486591.253972609119955
                        ],
                        [
                            1704518.120829694438726,
                            -486602.373676010407507
                        ],
                        [
                            1704499.474814986810088,
                            -486616.195156793750357
                        ],
                        [
                            1704462.182785570854321,
                            -486649.308665266784374
                        ],
                        [
                            1704450.505370986647904,
                            -486663.364605558745097
                        ],
                        [
                            1704446.330890082055703,
                            -486691.431835726136342
                        ],
                        [
                            1704439.763040125602856,
                            -486724.277428877539933
                        ],
                        [
                            1704417.398954425007105,
                            -486755.001802317623515
                        ],
                        [
                            1704386.607983271591365,
                            -486775.633582669310272
                        ],
                        [
                            1704379.17184128658846,
                            -486787.84742040297715
                        ],
                        [
                            1704376.455645711161196,
                            -486819.230516205076128
                        ],
                        [
                            1704373.806241830345243,
                            -486844.573686466144864
                        ],
                        [
                            1704353.768733487464488,
                            -486865.808366309851408
                        ],
                        [
                            1704338.239664521766827,
                            -486915.970015742408577
                        ],
                        [
                            1704264.791064496384934,
                            -486988.226065712166019
                        ],
                        [
                            1704252.579316356452182,
                            -487036.266548785904888
                        ],
                        [
                            1704236.126295617083088,
                            -487069.436045523558278
                        ],
                        [
                            1704206.270408186363056,
                            -487127.368261026567779
                        ],
                        [
                            1704202.08479533251375,
                            -487145.27601122460328
                        ],
                        [
                            1704210.444889090955257,
                            -487179.316377374110743
                        ],
                        [
                            1704204.210997606627643,
                            -487226.765254576923326
                        ],
                        [
                            1704255.918901080265641,
                            -487235.975922094017733
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure if it is related, but when I try to create a simple shapely polygon, it also creates something that I think it is an empty polygon, although it has an area > 0.

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import mapping, Polygon
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
>>> print(polygon.area)
0.5
>>> print(mapping(polygon))
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': ()}
```

and, plotting also doesn't show anything.

```
x, y = polygon.exterior.xy
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to use text to present textual data like GeoJSON. An image of text is unlikely to be legible on all devices, and requires someone to retype your data to attempt to use it.

Comment: I added a sample of the data

Comment: There are multiple polygons and polygons, I think that you would need to dissolve the multiple to be single polygons. I do not know for sure but I don't believe that you can have both types.

Comment: I also tried with only Polygons geojson and still the same.

Comment: Where in the world is this?

Comment: in Kinshasa, DRC

Comment: There seems to be _something_ wrong with your installation. Using your example data, I get non-empty Polygons. Also the small example with `print(mapping(polygon))` should actually print coordinates. How did you install geopandas and its dependencies?

Comment: I installed all packages with conda.